# DateTimeComparator behavior inconsistent with its javadoc

Tags: jodatime, datetime-comparison

I wanted to compare only the dates of two `org.joda.time.DateTime` values, so I was using the `DateTimeComparator.getDateOnlyInstance()` - but I saw some behavior that does not match with its javadoc. I wonder if someone here can explain that. The [javadoc of DateTimeComparator](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTimeComparator.html#compare%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object%29) says the following about its parameters and return value:

```
Parameters:
    lhsObj - the first object, logically on the left of a < comparison, null means now
    rhsObj - the second object, logically on the right of a < comparison, null means now
Returns:
    zero if order does not matter, negative value if lhsObj < rhsObj, positive value otherwise.
```

**Question 1:** Why does it return `zero if order does not matter`. The contract of this method as defined in the [Comparator interface's javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare%28T,%20T%29) says that the return value should be `a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as the first argument is less than, equal to, or greater than the second`. (Just occurred to me that `order does not matter` may be the author's way of saying that the objects are equal, but it is a confusing way to put it.)

**Question 2:** Consider the following code and its output:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    DateTime nowUTC = DateTime.now(DateTimeZone.UTC);
    int comparisonResult = DateTimeComparator.getDateOnlyInstance().compare(null, nowUTC);
    System.out.println("comparisonResult = " + comparisonResult);
}
```

The output (Remember that **null means now**, and **only the date** should be compared):

```
comparisonResult = -1
```

===
Additional info after reading first answer and some more experimenting:

Agreed that `null` means "now in default system timezone" but if you compare entire date time value of `DateTime.now(DateTimeZone.UTC)` and `null`, they are the same (see additional code below). That seems right to me because **now** in any timezone is the same instant. However, individual fields could be different. So, yesterday, I compared date only when date was different in UTC and PST (my default system timezone), I got the expected result = 1 because date in UTC was greater. At this time, though the dates are the same in both zones, but the comparator seems to say that the date in UTC is **less** than date in PST, which is never possible.

Test code:

public static void main(String[] args) {

```
System.out.println("Printing DateTime.now(DateTimeZone.UTC), and (DateTime)null using formatter.withZoneUTC()");
System.out.println("\tDateTime.now(DateTimeZone.UTC)\t= " +
        DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss-z").withZoneUTC().print(DateTime.now(DateTimeZone.UTC)));
System.out.println("\t(DateTime)null\t\t\t= " +
        DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss-z").withZoneUTC().print((DateTime)null));
System.out.println();

System.out.println("Printing (DateTime)null using formatter with default timezone");
System.out.println("\t(DateTime)null\t\t\t= " + DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss-z").print((DateTime)null));
System.out.println();

System.out.println("Comparing date only of DateTime.now(DateTimeZone.UTC) (LHS) and null (RHS)");
int dateOnlyComparisonResult = DateTimeComparator.getDateOnlyInstance().compare(DateTime.now(DateTimeZone.UTC), null);
System.out.println("\tdateOnlyComparisonResult\t= " + dateOnlyComparisonResult);
System.out.println();

System.out.println("Comparing entire date time value of DateTime.now(DateTimeZone.UTC) and null");
int instantComparisonResult = DateTimeComparator.getInstance().compare(DateTime.now(DateTimeZone.UTC), null);
System.out.println("\tinstantComparisonResult\t\t=  " + instantComparisonResult);
```

}

Output:

```
Printing DateTime.now(DateTimeZone.UTC), and (DateTime)null using formatter.withZoneUTC()
    DateTime.now(DateTimeZone.UTC)  = 2016-02-11T19:26:07-UTC
    (DateTime)null          = 2016-02-11T19:26:08-UTC

Printing (DateTime)null using formatter with default timezone
    (DateTime)null          = 2016-02-11T11:26:08-PST

Comparing date only of DateTime.now(DateTimeZone.UTC) (LHS) and null (RHS)
    dateOnlyComparisonResult    = -1

Comparing entire date time value of DateTime.now(DateTimeZone.UTC) and null
    instantComparisonResult     =  0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Answer to question 1:**

I agree that the phrase "zero if order does not matter" is confusing. It might better be replaced by "zero if temporal objects are equal" or similar. You can post an issue or even a pull request on the github-location of Joda-Time to suggest your preferred description.

**Answer to question 2:**

`Null` value does not mean simply now, but **now in default system timezone**. So only following code works:

```
DateTime nowDefaultZone = DateTime.now(DateTimeZone.getDefault());
int comparisonResult = 
  DateTimeComparator.getDateOnlyInstance().compare(null, nowDefaultZone);
System.out.println("comparisonResult = " + comparisonResult); // 0
```

Anyway, I strongly recommend not to use this null-"feature" but specify explicit timezone references because interpreting `null` as anything related to "now" is not per se intuitive.

Comment: Added some more code and its output. Why does `DateTimeComparator.getDateOnlyInstance(obj1,obj2)` think that the date in UTC is **less than** date in PST when they are both the same?

Comment: I do not plan to use the null-"feature" in my code. It's just that yesterday, while stepping through my code in the debugger, I saw that one of the arguments to the date-only compare method was unintentionally null. Because null means now and the other arg was `DateTime.now(DateTimeZone.UTC)`, if compare returned 0, it would have broken my code - but it did not return 0. That got me digging deeper into this null-"feature". :-)

Comment: @AjoyBhatia Yes, null handling in Joda-Time is evil IMHO. Anyway, I will try to find some time later to check the updated part of your question and see if Joda-Time has a bug there or not. Thanks for your studies.